# How to retrieve Tag_IDs for a post in WordPress?

Tags: php, tags, wordpress-theming

I need to display the IDs of the tags for a post. I've tried

```
$myTopics_id = '';
$tags = get_the_tags();
        
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $myTopics_id .= $tag->tag_ID;
}
```

inside the loop to get the tags to be displayed here:

```
<div onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'" data-topics="<?php echo $myTopics_id; ?>">
```

but it doesn't display anything, the string simply stays empty:

```
<div onclick="http://localhost/posts/" data-topics="">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: thanks to User biesior, I have changed my code to this now:

```
<?php $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); 
        
            /* Get Category ID */
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $mySection_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;

            /* ------- */

            /* Get Tag IDs */
            $myTopics_id = '';
            $tags = get_tags();
            
            foreach($tags as $tag) {
                $myTopics_id .= $tag->term_id;
                $myTopics_id .= ", ";
            }

        ?>

            <div data-topics="<?php echo $myTopics_id; ?>" data-section="<?php echo $mySection_id; ?>">   
                ... content to be displayed ... 
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

but the result is still wrong, as it is adding up the term_ids instead of displaying it individually per post.

So, as an example, my current result is

```
<div data-topics="15, 16, 13, 12, 10, 8, 11, " data-section="3"> ... </div>
```

As you can see, the current category per post is being displayed correct. But data-topics value is wrong and the same on every single post.
It is possible that there is more than one tag per post. So it would be correct if the result would be let's say

```
<div data-topics="15, 16, " data-section="3"> ... </div>
```

for the first post, then

```
<div data-topics="13, " data-section="7"> ... </div>
```

for the second

```
<div data-topics="12, 10, 8, " data-section="1"> ... </div>
```

for the third post and so on and so on.

But currently every post has the same values for data-topics ("15, 16, 13, 12, 10, 8, 11, "), so there seems to be an error in the loop or in the tag request. But I have no idea WHAT and WHERE.

Comment: What does `var_dump($tag)` placed in the `foreach()` loop shows?

Comment: where exactly? Before the line $myTopics_id .= $tag->tag_ID;  or  inside or ...? Sorry, I am new to WP Theming and PHP :-(

Comment: You can put it just at the beginning of the `forech()` loop. The clue is to make sure that `$tag` is fetched at all and is an object of required type. You can also check if `$tags` are fetched properly by adding `var_dump($tags)` in 3rd line of your PHP code. In future it's worth to enable i.e. Xdebug and configure your IDE to use it to be able to debug such things much easier instead of putting `var_dump()` everywhere.

Comment: ok, thanks. It renders quite a lot of stuff, eg object(WP_Term)#1084 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(15) ["name"]=> string(13) "Sample 1" ["slug"]=> string(13) "Sample 2" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(15)

Comment: As you can see this object hasn't field called `tag_ID`, did you mean `term_id`? or maybe you're fetching wrong objects? It's hard to guess with these few lines.

Comment: Yeah, I gave it a try with term_id, but it seems to adds up all ids on the post to one value. data-topics="15, 16, 13, 12, 10, 8, 11, "  instead of data-topics="15, 16" for let's say the ffirst post and then data-topics="13, " and so on. I'll edit my sample above with what I have changed so far

Comment: that's because you literally glues these IDs in your loop with `.=` operator. Sorry I'm not able to guess what is your apporach basing the samples, looks like you want to pass many ID's to one div.

Comment: I did this because one post can have multiple tags. Please, what's the right way to do it instead?

Comment: You have to describe your problem better, best, showing us what you wan to get and what you tried.

Comment: @biesior, you're right, I have extended sample and description above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post my solution here just in case someone arrives with the same problem:

```
$myTopics = get_the_tags();
$myTopics_id = "";
$myTopics_array = [];

if ($myTopics) {
    foreach($myTopics as $tag) {
         $myTopics_array[] = $tag->term_id;
    }
}

$myTopics_id = implode(',', $myTopics_array);


echo "<div data-topics='{$myTopics_id}'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to still start ana finish PHP block, that's enough to do it once. Second thing - you need to debug what does `get_tags()` return. In general this code *should* work, anyway have no possibility to check it without instance and/or sample data. Also, there are better ways to create comma separated list of values than just gluing (i.e. for avoiding trailing commas)

```php
<?php

$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array ('post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) :

    while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();

        /* Get Category ID */
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $mySection_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;

        /* Get Tag IDs */

        $tags = get_tags();
        var_dump($tags); // debug it to check what tags are returned in each `while` loop
        $tagsArray = [];


        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tagsArray[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
        $myTopics_id = implode(',', $tagsArray);

        echo "<div data-topics='{$myTopics_id}' data-section='{$mySection_id}'>
            ... content to be displayed ...
        </div>";


    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: I absolutly understand that it is difficult (impossible? to find a solution without real sample data. Unfortunatly the website I am working on is still work in progress and available only on my local machine. To cut a long story short: different code, same result. :-(((

Comment: PS: var_dump($tags);  as the exact same result on every post

Comment: That means it gets all tags, you need to check `get_tags() ` body

Comment: I need something like   the_tags();   just not echoing but as a return value. What is the correct equivalent? the_tags(); displays the right values (just as names instead of IDs, but well.... at least only the tag names per post not ALL at once).

Comment: @JonSnow I don't know, I don't even have an idea what is it from as you didn't specify source of the code. If it's your own methods publish them to some public repo so it can be linked into required file and line, if you bought it - contact the developer. Otherwise if you used some OpenSource feel free to fork it and adjust to your needs. Without knowing the code we're talking about my answer is just an advice or an opinion about general programming. It's like learning the world trough the key hole.

Comment: Hi, the first problem was get_tags() instead of get_the_tags(). And then I've just overseen your echo call and tried using my old html code with included PHP params here and there. I have posted my final solution below, just in case someone else is searching for a similiar solution. But I have marked your answer as accepted answer because you invested so much time and effort and it helped me getting on the right track! Thank you so much @biesior!

Comment: @JonSnow I appreciate that, however you should accept the **valid** answer, even if it's your own ;) Don't worry, I will not mind. Other thing is, that this is rather specific case, most probably we still don't know where is this code from, therefore I marked it for closing with "it was caused by typo" reason.

Comment: Caused by a typo? Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by this. I had a real issue in finding a solution for my problem. With your help I was able to get back on track and to finally solve it. It was not just a typo - it was the problem of a guy who is still learning PHP while doing his first ever WordPress Theming job.

Comment: As I understood that was caused by using the wrong method. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Compare the initial question with the final solution. It's not THAT different, but most important parts of it were wrong or even missing. So not just a typo, where I would have been missing a semicolon or used the wrong function name alone